# Adding new hard drives to my pc

Tags: hard-drive

Currently I have Ubuntu installed on a 120gb SSD, however I also have 3 more hard drives installed in the computer, 2 x 640gb in a RAID array and a 60gb SSD

What I am trying to achieve is to use the 640gb drive to store all my documents etc, the 120gb SSD to only Ubuntu and programs and then the final 60gb SSD to back up the most important documents from the 640gb drives, this must be an incremental back up system and not replace the file each time

*How can I achieve this ?*

Comment: Mount the raid array volume on /home in your fstab. I don't see using a 60GB SSD to backup an array more than 20 times it size, but if your going to cherry pick what you backup it will work until you run out of space on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [the official Ubuntu instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) to move your home partition to the RAID
2. Don't do anything and Ubuntu and programs will still be on the SSD!  **;-)**
3. Use [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools) to choose the right back-up program to back-up to the 60GB SSD.  The standard Ubuntu data file back-up solution is [Déjà Dup](https://askubuntu.com/a/2598/344926)